# c++ overloading operator << for std::string

Tags: c++, string, operator-overloading

I'm just now seeing another naive C++ code using sprintf to append C builtins into an array of chars, and I guess enough is enough.

I could help providing with simple, lightweight, appending and non-formatting functions for `std::string`, but as it would be check-in-ed into the team's common code, I want it to be perfect, so I need some advice **on the interface** of this feature (i.e. not on the actual implementation).

The following could be possible (I did not test it, it's just a hunch):

1. Overloading the "`+=`" operator (probably in another namespace than std or global)
2. Overloading the "`<<`" operator (again, in another namespace)
3. Providing non-operator non-member functions (I guess, again in another namespace)
4. Another easy solution I did not see?

What would be the pros and the cons of each solution (I have a preference for "`+=`", or even "`<<`") ?

#### Notes

- the point is not about formatting. If someone wants formatting, C++ streams are good for that. I just want simple, lightweight, one statement/function call appending.
- The use of another namespace would be because we are not authorized to add code to the std namespace, and I don't want to pollute the global namespace, so, yes, I guess the user would have to add a `using namespace SomeNamespace ;` as its done for the `<utility>`'s [rel_ops](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/utility/rel_ops/) namespace)
- I'm using `std::string` [which is not able, natively, to handle other types than itself, `char` and `char *`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator+=/). I want to extend that to handle other simple types.
- Using a stringstream weights too much in term of code (declaring the stream, appending, then retrieving the `.str()` to put it inside a string, etc. etc.), and the last thing I want is an syntactic sugared inline function instanciating a stringstream at each call). As you can see in the example below, the stringstream solution is **too verbose**:

.

```
// sprintf-like code with a char[] buffer:
sprintf(buffer, "%d", myDouble) ;

// stream-like code with a std::string buffer:
std::stringstream str ;
str << myDouble ;
buffer = str.str() ;

// example of desired code with a std::string buffer:
buffer += myDouble ;
```

Comment: Why not just refactor the code to use `std::string`? It has all you need and more.

Comment: What "string" type are you using?

Comment: @Björn Pollex : Not exactly. I need to use `std::stringstream` if I want to append other types than `std::string`, `char` or `char *`. I added a note to clarify that.

Comment: @Cody Gray : `std::string`. I added a note to clarify that.

Comment: So, what you are saying is that you want to create an `std::string & operator+=(std::string &, int)`? This does not sound like a good idea. Have you considered using `boost::lexical_cast`? Although, I guess it uses `stringstream` internally, so it would not fit your requirements.

Comment: There is, btw, a gnu autosprintf (as a part of gettext, I believe) — http://www.rootr.net/man/info/autosprintf — which you may find useful or which may give you inspiration.

Comment: @Björn Pollex : Even with specialization, boost::lexical_cast would return a temporary `std::string`, which I want to avoid (I want "appending", not "copying"). And yes, the += overload you mention is what I'm thinking about. I'm interested as to why it is not a good idea, so if you want to expand that into a full answer, I'm interested.

Comment: @paercebal: Overloading `operator +=` does not work as you have to extend `std::string` itself (as with all `X=` operators). Overloading `operator<<` is not good either, because you would have to extend `namespace std`, which is basically forbidden, or you write the overload somewhere else, but you then would have to ensure that this overload is unambiguous w.r.t. the standard and you would have to import your `operator<<` everywhere you need it (e.g. `using p::operator<<`) if it doesn't take custom types (see also Koenig Lookup)

Comment: @Griwes : You did misinterpreted my question. See the "desired code" example: I want to append a double into a string. So, yes, somehow, the double will be converted to an array of chars, and then appended to the string.

Comment: @phresnel : This is the kind of answer I would have liked to have, instead of a comment... :-) ... IIRC, I can add a non-member operator overload `operator +=` taking a reference to the string as the lhs parameter, and the desired type as the rhs parameter.

Answer (score 3):

I would use [`ostringstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostringstream/) and [stream manipulators](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/) to replace `sprintf`. It's not worth [reinventing the wheel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinventing_the_wheel).

Comment: Not a good solution. See my note about why stringstream is too much verbose to be of any use for what I want. I'm not about reinventing the wheel. I'm about adding lightweight syntactic sugar.

Comment: OK, you are the boss :) I just don't understand why do you think it's a good idea to reimplement such a complex functionality in order to save 2 lines of code (the creation of the oss object, and the .str() call). Okay, imagine you wrote something simple: you can concatenate strings and integers and doubles to an existing string. Then one of your colleagues writes this: `sprintf(buffer, "%08llu\t%08X", x, y);`. Do you really want to spend your life adding new formatting features again and again? I bet in a few months you would end up having something very similar to `ostringstream`...

Comment: Last month I reimplemented the string, number (including ordinary fractions), and date-time formatting functionality of Excel in C#. My employer could have used the existing formatting features of .NET, but he wanted a perfect match with Excel. This was a case, when you could not avoid "reinventing the wheel". Your case is different: you can use existing functionality, namely `ostringstream`, you don't have to duplicate a functionality that has already previously been created and optimized by others.

Comment: I'm not trying to offer a full-total-for-all-the-possible-cases solution. Only simple concatenation without formatting. So the `sprintf(buffer, "%08llu\t%08X", x, y)` would either remain as is, or be replaced by the stringstream equivalent. What I want now is, for the simple cases, to avoid the use of a C-style char array and a sprintf just because the coder didn't figure out how to use stringstream or didn't want to use it because, yes, 2 more useless lines of code is too much for what it is supposed to do.

Comment: ... And anyway, you don't even know what will be the implementation. I will be, perhaps, using stringstream inside. My question is about an interface, not the actual implementation. You're providing advice and solution to a question I didn't ask.

Answer (score 3):

1. What about `boost::format` ? Then you can write:

   ```
   std::string first("world");
   std::string s = (boost::format("hello %1%") % first).str();
   ```
2. Or create a wrapper class which you can use like so:

   ```
   int i(2);
   std::string s = (Format() + "Hello " + first + " " + i).str();
   ```

   And `Format()` something like (*without boost*) :

   ```
   class Format
   {
       public:
           template <typename T>
           Format &operator+(const T& v) {
               m_sstr << v; 
               return *this;
           };
           const std::string &str() const { return m_sstr.str(); };
       private:
           std::stringstream m_sstr;
   };
   ```

Comment: Right now, I'm more thinking about something like http://www.fastformat.org/ . For historical reasons (don't ask...), Boost is not really available for our app, and I even doubt I will be able to push for fastformat here, so this is why a lightweight function would be a good compromise.

Comment: @paercebal: I removed boost from the second option, maybe that would work for you?

Comment: +1. I like the implementation of the second solution, and its interface is interesting. I guess the stringstream could even become private member variable, to be reused each time the "append" operator would be called.

Comment: @paercebal: ofcourse, that would be even better, i'll edit my answer

Answer (score 3):

C++11 comes with an overloaded set of std::to_string functions.

example prototype:

```
std::string to_string( int value );
```

They are allowed to be overriden by the user (in C++11). You would need your own namespace for now.

You could implement your own set for the types of your choice. It would make for future-proof code.

you would use the code as:

```
std::string s;
s+=std::to_string(1);
```

Comment: +1 for the C++11 solution. While I don't like the fact a string is created, I learned something about C++11 while reading your post. Thanks... For the record, I was thinking about something like `std::string & append(std::string & p_string, const T & p_value) ;`

Comment: I think your suggestion is quite optimal, given your constraints.

Answer (score 0):

boost::lexical_cast provides a potential model for you here - write a function that can handle any of the datatypes you need, turn them into a string in the appropriate format for your purposes (and you can optimise that as much as you need to/are able to), and return them for use with operator+(string, string).

Specialise the function per type either with normal overloading or template specialisations according to your preference. lexical_cast uses templates so it can handle absolutely anything via whatever stream operators happen to be defined, but your use case is far narrower than this, and so you definitely can get some more performance out of it.

Comment: Not good. Even with specialization, boost::lexical_cast would return a temporary std::string, which I want to avoid (I want "appending", not "copying").

Comment: So, just make it be a function which takes the string to append to and the thing to append. Overloading operator += starts to look quite good then.

Comment: Yes, that was what I thought before asking the question. This is why I asked for advice on what was the pros/cons of using a function vs. an operator overload (either "`+=`" or "`<<`")