# overload cout without any user defined things in main in c++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

can i overload cout? just use the same code in main here

```
using namespace std;
int main() {

     cout << “overload" <<endl;
     return 0;
}
```

is it possible to overload << here? For example let the program prints "overload operator" instead of "overload"?

Comment: `void main` ? Ew...

Comment: you are using `<<` twice so "operator overload operator" seems more logical as a resut

Comment: :) void main work too. for some compilers as far as I know

Comment: @hasan: [Stroustrup disagrees](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#void-main). :-)

Comment: Don't care I test. and program is running :)

Comment: @hasan: Your compiler must be a rebel, then. :-) Seriously though, I don't quite know the answer to this.  Just wanted to address these other things.

Comment: In link it says that some compilers could accept it. but it's not a c++ standard. and there is some risk. and he detailed.

Comment: @user2756494 see this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8559467/c-overloading-operator-for-stdstring

Comment: @hasan: I know.  I just prefer what the standard says.

Comment: @hasan if you insist on bad practice that's up to you. It's up to us to inform new programmers about the correct ways.

Comment: @hasan what would be the benefit of writing code that only works on some compilers, when it is so easy to write portable code?

Answer (score 1):

`cout` is just an object in `namespace std`.

If your "overload" means using the same code to do other things, you can create a `namespace` on your own, create an instance named `cout`, then override the `<<` operator.